# It's only the fool who becomes anything. - Why is "anything" used?

Tags: word-choice, negation, polarity-items

Why is the word "anything" used even though it cannot be used for affirmative sentences?
Why isn't it "something"?
I would say it like “It is only a fool who becomes something.”

Comment: Why do you think "anything" cannot be used for negative sentences?

Comment: @stangdon, sorry, I've corrected to affirmative

Comment: That line looks like an "awkward" translation from Dostoyevsky's original Russian text. I'm not convinced a native speaker would naturally use "anything" there. I think the entire construction is inherently awkward anyway, but "something" would probably be better than "anything". It's not worth spending time on it, though, because a native speaker would probably use a completely different construction to start with

Comment: Perhaps something based on "Out of the mouths of babes and sucklings..." from the Bible, or a reference to the child pointing out that the emperor had no clothes,

Comment: We do use a related / similar expression in, say, *Only someone willing to wholeheartedly commit to his goal can **make something of himself***. But ***Only a fool can make something of himself*** would be a bit weird anyway (except *maybe* if you're reading it in Dostoyevsky's *The Fool*, which I assume is the original source).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the detailed answer! This is from Dostoevsky's "Notes from Underground". How would you express the sentence if you were editing it?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what Dostoyevsky's original is supposed to mean in the first place. But I'm guessing *you* might understand the original, so perhaps you could include some (much longer) English text telling us what he's trying to say. Which *may* be similar to the "Emperor's new clothes" context (innocent / unsophisticated people are sometimes capable of seeing and describing things more straightforwardly / honestly than "clever" people). Or it might be something more about how people who superficially appear foolish can sometimes be very successful in certain fields.

Comment: ...but I haven't read *The Fool*. For all I know, the entire book is just one long explanation of how and why foolish people are sometimes useful!

Comment: People sometimes say things like *If bumblebees were clever enough to understand Newton's laws of motion, they'd never have bothered trying to fly, because they'd have known flight was impossible for bumblebees*

Comment: I don't see any problem with either the choice of *anything* or the overall structure of the sentence here.  I agree that modern idiomatic English would probably be more likely to use *something*, but this version is perfectly understandable.

Comment: This doesn't look like anything a native English speaker would say. Although it is grammatically correct,  it doesn't really make any logical sense, especially without further context.  Using "something" makes no difference. It's still illogical. I'm going to assume this is either a misquote/mistranslation. Sorry.

Comment: I am baffled by the people who say this doesn't make sense.  Does it help to think of it this way? "Of the various kinds of people in the world - the genius, the fool, the saint, the sinner - it is only the fool who becomes anything different than what he already is."

Comment: Why do you think "anything" can't be used in affirmative sentences? For example, "You can be anything you want to be".

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, both *any* and *anything* can be used in positive sentences. However, the meaning is slightly different. It is often referred to as ***wide scope** any* or ***free choice** any.* It generally means there is no upper limit to something. However, negative polarity item *any* has narrow scope and usually means something like 'not even a little bit.'

Comment: @BillyKerr It makes sense to me, because I spent far too much time playing poker when I was an undergraduate. In some variants the Joker is a wild card; it is also a descendant of the Fool in a Tarot deck. So the Fool can become anything [that the player wants], although that is probably not what Dostoevsky meant...

Comment: @stangdon is correct; both "anything" and "something" in this phrase works exactly the same, even though these two words mean different things in other grammatical constructions.

Comment: The narrator in the story believes that in spite of reaching age forty, which he believes to be old, he hasn't become anything (as in perhaps in the sense of having some sort of status in society). He's consoling himself in a sour-grapes kind of way that, bah, becoming something is only for fools anyway. A non-fool like himself cannot seriously get into the game of becoming something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason that *anything* works here is because, although the sentence is technically positive polarity, it has a type of negative meaning.

Words like *anything*, *ever*, *at all*, and *yet* usually occur in negative sentences:

- *I have got anything **yet**. (ungrammatical)
- I haven't got anything **yet**.
- *I have **ever** been to Paris. (ungrammatical)
- I haven't **ever** been to Paris.

However, they can also occur in other sentences which have some type of negative meaning. For example, *yes/no* questions represent a choice between a positive and negative version of the proposition. So these work fine in yes/no questions:

- Have you got **anything** yet?
- Have you **ever** been to Paris?

These types of word are often known as ɴᴇɢᴀᴛɪᴠᴇ ᴘᴏʟᴀʀɪᴛʏ ɪᴛᴇᴍs. The environments they occur in are sometimes known as ɴᴇɢᴀᴛɪᴠᴇ ᴛʀɪɢɢᴇʀs.

The word *only*, which we see in the Original Poster's example, has a type of hidden negative meaning. Consider:

- Only Usain Bolt has run the 100m in under 9.6 seconds.

This sentence means the same as:

- **Nobody** has run the 100m in under 9.6 seconds, apart from Usain Bolt.

And because of the negative meaning involved, we can use negative polarity items such as *ever* here:

- Only Usain Bolt has **ever** run the 100m in under 9.6 seconds.

The word *only* is therefore often a negative trigger, allowing the use of words such as *any*, *every* and so forth.

The Original Poster's sentence is:

- It is only the fool who becomes **anything**.

This means the same as:

- Nobody becomes **anything**, apart from the fool.

This hidden negative meaning makes the use of *anything* possible here. Notice we could easily use other negative polarity items here too, for example *ever* or *at all*:

- It is only the fool who **ever** becomes **anything** **at all**.

Comment: Hello! You are incorrect about "anything" though; "If you like anything here, please feel free to take it." has no negative meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @user21820 Hi! You misread what I said, I think.  *Anything, ever, at all* etc don't have negative meanings, they just occur  in negative environments. :-) However, I have a surprise for you!!! Your particular sentence is a conditional: ***If you like anything here**, please feel free to take it*.  The protasis, as its called in the trade, is the bit in bold there. Conditional protases are just like polar questions, they explicitly allow for two possibilities a positive one and a negative one.  In your case a) that you like something or b) that you **don't**!

Comment: @user21820 And it's the negative possibility that licences the use of negative polarity items!

Comment: I don't agree, but I don't have the time for a detailed rebuttal, so never mind! =)